# jQuery toggle function not working as expected with each and click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide an element `+Details` after it has been clicked and show `xClose`, and vice versa, but it's not working. Also when I click on `+Details` all of the divs are opened even though I used `each()` function. When you click on `xClose` I want the `eventInfo` text to show, but I can't even get the `xClose` text to show.

```js
$('.openInfo').each(function (index) {
  $(this).click(function () {
    $('.eventInfo').toggleClass('show');
    $('openInfo').toggleClass('hide');
    $('closeInfo').toggleClass('show');
  });
});


$('.closeInfo').each(function (index) {
  $(this).click(function () {
    $('.eventInfo').toggleClass('show');
    $('closeInfo').toggleClass('hide');
    $('openInfo').toggleClass('show')
  });
});
```

```css
  .event{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .eventInfo, .closeInfo{
    display: none;
  }

  .show{
    display: block;
  }

  .hide{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
            <p class="openInfo"><span>+</span>Details</p>
            <p class="eventInfo"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            <p class="closeInfo"><span>x</span>Close</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="event">
            <p class="openInfo"><span>+</span>Details</p>
            <p  class="eventInfo"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            <p class="closeInfo"><span>x</span>Close</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Points to keep in mind: (1) jQuery methods (e.g. toggleClass) will affect all the elements that match the specified selector, e.g. .eventInfo. (2) the 'closeInfo' and 'openInfo' selectors are invalid, because they are missing the class dot . notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach click listeners to `.closeInfo` and `.openInfo` and then inside the event, need to [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the classes within its parent `.event`.

```js
$('.closeInfo, .openInfo').on('click', function() {
  let $closestEvent = $(this).closest('.event');
  $closestEvent.find('.eventInfo, .closeInfo, .openInfo' ).toggle();
});
```

```css
.event {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.eventInfo,
.closeInfo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="event">
  <p class="openInfo"><span>+</span>Details</p>
  <p class="eventInfo"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  <p class="closeInfo"><span>x</span>Close</p>
</div>

<div class="event">
  <p class="openInfo"><span>+</span>Details</p>
  <p class="eventInfo"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  <p class="closeInfo"><span>x</span>Close</p>
</div>
```